# Drawing circles surrounding a texture using libgdx

Tags: libgdx, textures, geometry

I’m new in libgdx and I’m developing a simple game which consists in multiple items (fruits, balls, flowers, etc.) that are falling down through the screen.
The goal is to fling them all to a certain position on the screen.
These objects bounce on each other as well as on obstacles that are scattered on the screen.
To program the physics involved in perform a bounce, I delimited each item with a "collision" circle.
Since I'm new using libgdx, it was hard for me to put the circles in the correct position (over the texture of each item) and move them accordingly.
Is there a way to debug that? I mean, is there a way to show each circle that surrounds each texture in order to corroborate if it is well positioned or not?
I tried using ShapeRenderer and Pixmap unsuccessfully...any idea? Thks

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7108503)  your question

Comment: Not sure if I understood you well, but for every texture you can read widht and height and if you split them to half you'll get texture (and circle) center. And if you use pythagorean theorem you can easily calculate circle diameter. Also if you want to rotate those texutre you can set rotation points to those center coords you calculated so object will stay in the circle and rotate around the center.

Comment: Look at ShapeRenderer. It works sort of like SpriteBatch, but you can use it to draw debug shapes on top of your sprites.

Comment: I could work out my issue.
I have used ShapeRenderer to draw shapes without nesting invocations with spriteBach. That was my first problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
game.batch.begin();
// draw...
game.batch.end();

game.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
game.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
game.shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);

// draw boundingRectangle's sprite: shapeRenderer.rect(getBoundingRectangle().x, getBoundingRectangle().y, getBoundingRectangle().width, getBoundingRectangle().height);

game.shapeRenderer.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question but if you are using Box2D physics and you have created physics objects correctly, I think you should check Box2DDebugRenderer. Box2DDebugRenderer renders the physics shape of the object to your screen. There's more info about Box2DDebugRenderer and other stuff in the LibGDX Developer's Guide in the Github under Extensions->Physics->Box2D.